# Error in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Goodafternoon community! total beginner here. I am developing my first android app and have downloaded all what is required in running Eclipse Juno as well as files from SDK manager. But when I'm creating a new Android Application Project I encounter a couple of errors already. 
It says,

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
(^in red)

AND...

WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\Nokia\thesis2\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
(^ in black)

Can anyone help me. Thank you very much everyone! :-D more power to you guys!

Comment: it's appcompact issue in your project explorer u can see appcomact lib project

Comment: project right click Propeties->android-> Library Add->select appcompact library project

Answer (score 0):

You should add `support v7` library in your project. If you are not installed it using SDK manager,
[Android developer](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) site will help you.

After that the `AppCompat` Can be found at

```
android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
```

You need to reference this `AppCompat` in your android project.

> Import the library to eclipse.
>
> 1. Right click on your android project.
> 2. Goto Properties.
> 3. Select Android.
> 4. Click Add Library and reference the same.

Clean and Rebuild your project